# Difference between 'multiple' and 'tags' mode in Antd Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

What is the difference between the 2 modes `multiple` and `tags` in Antd [`Select`](https://ant.design/components/select)? I tried both and they look the same to me.

```js
<Select mode="tags" {...}>
  {children}
</Select>
```

```js
<Select mode="multiple" {...}>
  {children}
</Select>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like there is no difference except that you can create new options in `tags` mode (by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> if the value in the input field does not exist). You can't extend the options like that using `multiple` mode.